# The data from datastream of minio is coming multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, minio

The data (in `Uint8Array` format) from the minio client sometimes comes only once, but other times it comes 3-4 times.

```js
s3Client.getObject(
  bucketname,
  `folder/file.jpg`,
  function(err, dataStream) {
  
    if (err) {
      onError();
    }
    
    dataStream.on("data", function(data) {
      console.log(data, "data");
      const urlData = new Blob([data]);
    }
  }
)
```

The console is giving me the response:

```
Uint8Array(65536) [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 8, 10, 12, 20, 13, 12, 11, 11, 12, 25, 18, 19, 15, 20, 29, 26, 31, 30, 29, 26, 28, 28, 32, 36, 46, 39, 32, 34, 44, 35, 28, 28, 40, 55, 41, 44, 48, 49, 52, 52, 52, 31, 39, 57, 61, 56, 50, 60, 46, 51, 52, 50, 255, 219, 0, 67, 1, 9, 9, 9, 12, 11, 12, …] "data"
```

```
Uint8Array(36498) [90, 44, 146, 187, 26, 132, 98, 175, 32, 178, 248, 209, 107, 36, 152, 189, 209, 166, 133, 63, 189, 12, 194, 67, 249, 16, 191, 206, 189, 7, 71, 214, 180, 253, 122, 201, 110, 244, 235, 149, 154, 18, 112, 113, 193, 83, 232, 65, 228, 26, 230, 181, 31, 133, 222, 27, 188, 129, 197, 181, 180, 150, 115, 30, 146, 67, 35, 28, 31, 247, 88, 145, 143, 202, 160, 248, 125, 225, 13, 71, 194, 218, 134, 171, 246, 199, 70, 130, 80, 139, 11, 198, 220, 73, 130, 220, 145, 212, 17, 158, …] "data"
```

And after refreshing the page for the same image, the console is:

```
Uint8Array(102034) [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 8, 10, 12, 20, 13, 12, 11, 11, 12, 25, 18, 19, 15, 20, 29, 26, 31, 30, 29, 26, 28, 28, 32, 36, 46, 39, 32, 34, 44, 35, 28, 28, 40, 55, 41, 44, 48, 49, 52, 52, 52, 31, 39, 57, 61, 56, 50, 60, 46, 51, 52, 50, 255, 219, 0, 67, 1, 9, 9, 9, 12, 11, 12, …] "data"
```

I am already calling it in `useEffect`. It is hitting the minio client single time but `function (err, dataStream)` is not giving consistent data.

Answer (score 0):

Because it appends different chunks of the file each time.
You can get the entire data from dataSteram.on("end", ...)

```
let size = 0
minioClient.getObject('mybucket', 'photo.jpg', function(err, dataStream) {
 if (err) {
  return console.log(err)
 }
 dataStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
  size += chunk.length
 })
 dataStream.on('end', function() {
  console.log('End. Total size = ' + size)
  console.log(dataStream)
  console.log(dataStream.socket._tlsOptions.session)
 })
 dataStream.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err)
 })
})
```